# Extracting plaintext from XML with embedded links using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to extract text from XML similar to the following:

`<p>This is a paragraph <a href='http://link.com'>with an embedded link</a> with more text afterwards</p>`

I would like the extracted text to maintain the URL within the the paragraph, like this:

`This is a paragraph with an embedded link (http://link.com) with more text afterwards`

It is fairly straight forward to extract the text:

`<xsl:value-of select="p"/>` and the URL: `<xsl:value-of select="p/a/@href"/>`, but I am struggling to think of a way to embed the URL within the extracted text using XSLT.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

If there is no easy way to do this I may end up either doing some pre-processing of the text to embed the URL and just use XSLT to extract all the text from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' (', @href, ')')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Template `<xsl:template match="text()">` matches text nodes and simply outputs them.

Template `<xsl:template match="a">` outputs content of `a` element and its `(@href)` value.

Comment: Some explanation of what you are doing would be helpful :D. Do that and you get +1.

Comment: Good approach but rough on the edges: it relies on some whitespace being there in the surrounding text nodes -- generally, this maynot be the case.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev True, some of the links may be at the end of sentences or followed by text in a sentence. I'll see if I can get rid of that issue.